# Custom culture add in Umbraco 10.3

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

[image: 1]

We have some cultures only by default,
I would like to add some custom cultures

Thanks

```
ex: en-IN is available
    ar-IN I would like to add.
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to add this to the operating system cultures as it enumerates through those under the hood. Something similar to as mentioned in here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureandregioninfobuilder?view=netframework-4.8

The problem then comes if you host on something like Azure Apps - as you cannot change the system cultures. Unfortunately, the way many .NET based CMS link their language / locale settings to system culture seems to create many problems with many modern hosting solutions where you don't have full access. EPiServer is similarly affected.